# Is there a way to directly recover the subject and predicate parameters from a Wikidata statement node?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I would like to find a direct way of retrieving the triple (i.e., the subject, the main predicate, and the object) that is implicit in a statement node in Wikidata.

As an example, in the Wikidata Query Service, one can query

```
SELECT ?subject ?statement ?object
WHERE 
{
 wd:Q2629845 p:P54 ?statement.
 ?statement ps:P54 wd:Q631.}
}
```

i.e., get me the value for `?statement` that represents the statement node that Massimo Marazzina (`wd:Q2629845`) plays for FC Inter Milan (`wd:Q631`). In this example, the binding one gets for `?statement` is `wds:q2629845-C6C57DFC-1340-4373-8B24-FB718AA8A949`.

The subject, main predicate, and object implicit in this statement (i.e., the triple <`wd:Q2629845 wdt:P54 wd:Q631`>) are all recoverable from the statement node itself. Recovering the parameters encoded in a statement node *seems* to be the very kind of thing for which the wikibase service exists, so I imagine there is some predicate that can be used to *directly* query for these parameters.

One can reconstruct the triple <`wd:Q2629845 wdt:P54 wd:Q631`> that is encoded in the statement node by querying

```
SELECT ?subject ?directPredicate ?object
WHERE 
{
 ?subject ?predicate wds:q2629845-C6C57DFC-1340-4373-8B24-FB718AA8A949.
 ?predicate (^wikibase:claim)/wikibase:directClaim ?directPredicate.
 ?predicate (^wikibase:claim)/wikibase:statementProperty ?statementProperty.
 wds:q2629845-C6C57DFC-1340-4373-8B24-FB718AA8A949 ?statementProperty ?object.
}
```

This, however, is pretty roundabout and involves querying with an open variable in the predicate position (which I'd like to avoid).

Ideally, a solution would be something like a wikibase predicate (call it "`wikibase:mainPredicate`") that, given a statement node `STATEMENT`, would allow one to query

```
SELECT ?mainPredicate
WHERE
{
  STATEMENT wikibase:mainPredicate ?mainPredicate.
}
```

where `?mainPredicate` gets us the primary predicate used in the statement node itself.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is *no*. Check `DESCRIBE wds:q2629845-C6C57DFC-1340-4373-8B24-FB718AA8A949`.

Comment: Thank you! If you wouldn't mind a follow-up, do you know if one can reasonably assume that there will be a unique "entity-to-statement" predicate among those results?

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you want, but a hacky weird query might be `select ?prop {
  
  wds:q2629845-C6C57DFC-1340-4373-8B24-FB718AA8A949 ?p ?o
  filter(strstarts(str(?p), str(ps:))) 
  BIND(URI(concat(str(p:), strafter(str(?p), str(ps:)))) as ?prop)
}`

Comment: Well, I indeed I meant `BIND(URI(concat(str(wdt:), strafter(str(?p), str(ps:)))) as ?prop)` to build `wdt:P54`- sorry

Comment: It was clear from context, no worries! Thanks for the clarification!